# Dynamically add images to collectionview with filepicker using .net maui C# markup

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, maui

I am new to .net maui . im trying to add images inside a scrollview using a filepicker but all i get is just the path location of the file.

Can you tell me what im doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    static string PickedImage;
    List<ImageSource> images = new List<ImageSource>();
    CollectionView stack = new CollectionView();
  
    public MainPage() {
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView();
          
        async void PickfileBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await PickAndShow(PickOptions.Default);
            PickedImage = result.FullPath;
            images.Add(PickedImage);
            stack.ItemsSource(images);
            scrollView.Content = stack;
        }
        
        Grid grid = new Grid
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(20),
            ColumnDefinitions = Columns.Define(
            (Column.image, Auto)),
            RowDefinitions = Rows.Define(
            (Row.button, Star)),

            Children =
            {
                new ScrollView { Content = stack}
                .Column(Column.image),
                new Button { Text = "file picker", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }
                .Row(Row.button)
               .Invoke(button => button.Clicked += PickfileBtn),
            }
        };

        Content = grid;
        }

    enum Row { button }
    enum Column { image, Text }

    public async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
    {

        try
        {
            var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    using var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                    var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // The user canceled or something went wrong
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

[what i get with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l38AY.jpg)

What i expect to happen is having images added to the scrollview after one another vertically.

Comment: You should read about ViewModels and ObservableCollections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use following code:

Page.xaml:

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Button Text="add" 
                Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
                
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sample}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Source_}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

VM:

```
public class VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Image_> Sample {get; private set;} = new();
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }
    public VM()
    {
        TapCommand = new Command(Show);
    }
    private void Show()
    {
        Sample.Add(new Image_() { Source_ = "ddd.png" });
    }
}
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  public MainPage ()
  {
    InitializeComponent ();
    BindingContext = new VM ();
  }
}
```

And then combine your filepicker.

Comment: it solved my problem, however datatype of DataTemplate needed to be included in DataTemplate like so <DataTemplate x:DataType="Image"> and binding image to Source but its not C# markup but anyway i guess i wont be using that anymore